# Can you specify an activity timeout for WebSocket4Net websocket

Tags: c#, websocket4net

Opened a WebSocket using a WebSocket4Net client against a relatively quiet server. After 4 minutes the socket is receiving a close message. After 4 minutes the socket is receiving a close message if no other message activity is received on the socket.

Is there a timeout that is defined in the WebSocket? I'm trying to determine for certain that the WebSocket is closing from a timeout as the server has no activity timeout set so would allow the socket to remain connected indefinitely.

Answer (score 2):

According to Kerry Jiang on this thread, http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/discussions/403988, the answer is no. The issue lies in the websocket server disconnecting.